# Bloomberg API DVD_HIST request with DVD_START_DT & DVD_END_DT override

Tags: java, api, bloomberg

First let me apologize for my bad english.

I'm writing a Java servlet, HistoricalDataRequest (BDH Excel Add-In function) & ReferenceDataRequest (BDP Excel Add-In function) work fine.

And now I'm trying to request a DVD_HIST (BDS Excel  Add-In function), but when I set the override for DVD_START_DT & DVD_END_DT I get this exception:

> com.bloomberglp.blpapi.NotFoundException: Element: DVD_START_DT not
>   found in: ReferenceDataRequest

I'm using this command:

```
request.set("DVD_START_DT", "20151101");

request.set("DVD_END_DT", "20151231");
```

Anybody found this problem before?
Some ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to set overrides on a Historical/Reference request is:

```
Element overrides = request.GetElement("overrides");
Element override1 = overrides.AppendElement();
override1.SetElement("fieldId", "DVD_START_DT");
override1.SetElement("value", "20151101");
Element override2 = overrides.AppendElement();
override2.SetElement("fieldId", "DVD_END_DT");
override2.SetElement("value", "20151231");
```